# WAMP - localhost can share to someone

Tags: wordpress, ip, localhost, wamp, ip-address

I'm not really sure if this is possible, I have a WordPress theme installed and customized using localhost + wamp. Can my colleague view my site w/o uploading it to the server? I mean, can i share a IP address so that he can view it too?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at port forwarding. You will need to setup a port forwarding rule for Port 80 to forward to the localhost and port that is running your app locally. This way when your friend enters your ipaddress the request will be forwarded to your localhost and he will be able to view the page. Here is an article that discuss [Port Forwarding](http://netforbeginners.about.com/od/p/f/What-Is-Port-Forwarding.htm).

Comment: Actually, i did edit my httpd.conf file in my apache... and type the Allow, Deny and Allow from all.. my friend was able to access my website locally, but the layout is broken...

Comment: What u mean layout is broken? Different browsers can show page differently. Are you both using same browsers?